# How to write in memory integration test for a WebApi secured by OpenId Connect, cookie authentication and hosted by NancyFx and Owin

Tags: integration-testing, owin, nancy, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a WabApi project which uses Owin and NancyFX. The api is secured by OpenId Connect and cookie authentication.

I have to write some in memory integration tests using HttpClient, which is quite easy as long as you don't try to use authentication based on OpenId Connect and cookie.

Does anyone know how to prepare a proper authentication cookie for HttpClient to let it connect with WebApi as authenticated user?

Currently I'm able to do some http calls to get the proper access token, id token etc. from OpenId Connect provider (implemented by IdentityServer v3), but I have no idea how to prepare authentication cookie for HttpClient.

PS: I uses Hybrid flow for OpenId Connect

Below you can find some of my files.

Server project:
AppStartup for WebApi:

The server application hosts WebApi and OpenId Connect provider (IdentityServer v3) at the same time, so its app starup looks like this:

```
public class ServerAppStartup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {          
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory {...};
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "server app",
                SigningCertificate = ...,
                RequireSsl = false,
                Factory = factory,
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions {
                    RememberLastUsername = true 
                },
                EnableWelcomePage = false
            });
        });

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ClientCookie");

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = "ClientCookie",
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "ClientCookie",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = app.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(),

            Authority = options.BaseUrl+ "identity",

            ClientId = options.ClientId,                
            RedirectUri = options.RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = options.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile offline_access",                                

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    /* stuff to get ACCESS TOKEN from CODE TOKEN */
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {                       
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }            

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();        

        app.UseNancy();
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
    }
```

Sample nancy module (something like controller in MVC or WebApi):

```
using System;
using Nancy.ModelBinding;
using Nancy.Security;
namespace Server.Modules
{
    public class UsersModule : BaseModule  
    {
        public UsersModule() : base("/users")
        {
            Get["/getall"] = parameters =>
            {
                this.RequiresMSOwinAuthentication();
                ...
                return ...;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Integration test project:

Test server to let me run WebApi in memory:

```
 public class TestServer: IDisposable
{
    private Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> _appFunc;
    public static CookieContainer CookieContainer;      
    public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }
    // I uses OwinHttpMessageHandler becaouse it can handle http redirections
    public OwinHttpMessageHandler Handler { get; private set; }
    public HttpClient HttpClient => new HttpClient(Handler) { BaseAddress = BaseAddress };

    public static TestServer Create()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();           
        var result = new TestServer();

        var appBuilder = new AppBuilder();
        appBuilder.Properties["host.AppName"] = "WebApi server";

        /* Use configuration of server app */
        ServerAppStartup.Configuration(appBuilder);

        result._appFunc = appBuilder.Build();
        result.Handler = new OwinHttpMessageHandler(result._appFunc)
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            AutoRedirectLimit = 1000,
            CookieContainer = CookieContainer,
            UseCookies = true          
        };          

        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {           
        Handler.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Sample test:

```
namespace ServerSpec.Specs.Users
{
    public class GetAllUsersSpec
    {   
        private TestServer _server;

        public GetAllUsersSpec(){
            server = TestServer.create();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void should_return_all_users()
        {
            /* here I will get error because http client or rather its cookie handler has no authentication cookie */
            var users = Get("/users/getall");
            ...
        }

        public TResponse Get<TResponse>(string urlFragment)
        {
            var client = server.HttpClient();

            var httpResponse = client.GetAsync(urlFragment).Result;
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>().Result;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the unit and integration tests in this project:

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.Owin.PopAuthentication

It shows doing in-memory integration testing with IdentityServer in one pipeline, and a (fake) web api in another pipeline that accepts tokens.